# How can I include a package in a new folder?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a folder Scenario that contains five packages and I would like to include this folder in another one, devel.
So I would like to change the path from /home/Scenario to /home/devel/Scenario but I couldn't find any command to do that automatically.
Do I need to change the path manually in every files in each package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37672/how-can-i-include-a-package-in-a-new-folder?/) by [Marie](https://answers.ros.org/users/2752/marie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What files are you concerned about? If you didn't use any hard coded, absolute paths in any of your sources / scripts, then the location of a package should not affect its proper functioning (or building).

As long as packages are (indirectly) on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, things should be fine. ROS will sort out the locations of packages during building and execution, using the information in the `manifest.xml` file (among other things). `rosmake` also sets up the include paths for C++ code.

For `bash` scripts, use `rospack`: to make use of a file inside `my_package` in the `/home/me/somedir` directory, instead of doing:

```
do_something_with /home/me/somedir/my_package/my_file
```

do:

```
do_something_with `rospack find my_package`/my_file
```

this way it doesn't matter where `my_package` is, as long as `rospack` can find it.

tl;dr: stay away from absolute paths and things should 'just work'.

PS: a `rosmake --pre-clean` might be a good thing to do after moving them.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-02**:
cmake hard-codes paths. When moving an already compiled ros package to a different directory, it is important to call `make clean` in that package before building it. `rosmake --pre-clean` does that in all packages in the dependency tree.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-02**:
:) just added that, but thanks.